# Gridview Change background color based on date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I would like to change the background color on my gridview based on current date. The code below works, but the future date which will be colored in blue starts two days later instead of 1 day which is tomorrow. Am I missing something in the code or should it be modified differently? .

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                    Dim data As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)("Date").ToString())
                    Dim diff As TimeSpan
                    diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(data)
                    Dim days As Integer = diff.Days
                    'Yellow = past date / White = current date / Blue = future date
                    If days > 0 Then
                        e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFBB") 'past date'
                    ElseIf days < 0 Then
                        e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#BAD8FF") 'future date'
                    ElseIf days = 0 Then 'present date
                        'do nothing
                    End If
                End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the `Date` property of `DateTime` which truncates the time:

```
Dim data = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
Dim day As Date = data.Row.Field(Of Date)("Date").Date
Dim daysDiff As Int32 = (Now.Date - day).Days
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I applied your suggestion within my code but got an error on "Dim day As Date = data.Row.Field(Of Date)("Date").Date" error message "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. Any ideas?

Comment: I solved the issue using your suggestion I modified the code to `Dim data As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)("Date").ToString())
                    Dim day As Date = data.Date
                    Dim daysDiff As Int32 = (Now.Date - day).Days`, which produced no errors and tomorrow's date is now highlighted in blue. Should I write it differently or leave it as is since it works?

Comment: @g_shockTan: Why do you convert your date-field to string and then back to `Date`, that is inefficient and can cause localization issues.Do you store the date as string?

Comment: No. It's stored as DateTime in SQL. What do you suggest on how it should be written? I tried the above code but got an error that the specified cast is not valid.

Comment: It's difficult to help without the code and the exception(with stack-trace). In general you should use the correct type in the first place. If you have used a `DataAdapter` to fill the table, the field's type should be `Date` already.